# Will Steam not run if its partition is copied to another using dd?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, dd, steam

If I have Steam installed on one windows partition and then I copy that windows partition into another partition using dd, will Steam not run in that new partition? If so is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have created shortcuts to directly launch games, they will no longer work unless you modify them. Aside from that, your Steam launcher will still work and your games *should* work unless they were, well... badly designed. If you encounter errors, you could also try to remove any existing cached data and retry.

I've done it for my Steam installation and everything went fine, no side issues (Win7 too). Just ensure that the filesystem is the same as a Windows installation.

Were it to fail, all you'd have to do is to put back your Steam folder back were it was.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What did you mean : "Just ensure that the filesystem is the same as a Windows installation?" Does that mean that the new partition should be ntfs, or did you mean something else?

Comment: That's exactly what I meant :)

Comment: Thanks. I am preparing my computer for a complete fresh re-installation of windows -> steam -> skyrim. I am a little nervous, that something horrible might come my way on this incredible adventure, but we will see what happens.

Comment: I just tested the copying of windows into another ntfs partition, however the bios did not detect it? I was unable to boot into the back up copy. What happened?

Comment: Hm, my bad... I thought you only talked about Steam itself. If you want to make your Windows partition bootable again you have several steps to perform (including modifying Windows' boot file and registry). All the required steps are detailed here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=916146